stackexchange for litecoins?
...Repost...
Is there any stackexchange forum for litecoins like bitcoins?
I would want to know about its mining process and all from credible sources on exchange.Yes, there are blogs and sites which help you do it but lets say i have been fooled more than once in it!

Given that you are even using the [tag:litecoin] tag on your post, this question seems rather confused. In case it wasn't clear: Litecoin is on-topic here. Perhaps you'd be interested in having a look at our [tour].

hi...yes, i did see the tag, was just wondering for a dedicated exchange site.In this case, i am posting a litecoin question on bitcoin exchange and these are 2 different crypto-currencies! :)

From the help:

The Bitcoin stack exchange is for users and enthusiasts of Bitcoin and
  related technologies. If you have a question about […] a
  cryptocurrency or technology derived directly from Bitcoin such as
  Namecoin or Litecoin […] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So although there is no dedicated Litecoin stackexchange, you can ask your questions here.
